# Normalize blocks/sub-matrices within a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, normalization, submatrix

I want to normalize (i.e., 0-1) blocks/sub-matrices within a square matrix based on row/col names. It is important that the normalized matrix correspond to the original matrix. The below code extracts the blocks, e.g. all col/row names == "A" and normalizes it by its max value. How do I put that matrix of normalized blocks back together so it corresponds to the original matrix, such that each single value of the normalized blocks are in the same place as in the original matrix. I.e. you cannot put the blocks together and then e.g. sort the normalized matrix by the original's matrix row/col names.

```
#dummy code
mat <- matrix(round(runif(90, 0, 50),),9,9)
rownames(mat) <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],3)
colnames(mat) <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],3)

mat.n <- matrix(0,nrow(mat),ncol(mat), dimnames = list(rownames(mat),colnames(mat)))
for(i in 1:length(LETTERS[1:3])){
    ? <- mat[rownames(mat)==LETTERS[1:3][i],colnames(mat)==LETTERS[1:3][i]] / max(mat[rownames(mat)==LETTERS[1:3][i],colnames(mat)==LETTERS[1:3][i]])
    #For example,
    mat.n[rownames(mat)==LETTERS[1:3][i],colnames(mat)==LETTERS[1:3][i]] <- # doesn't work
}
```

**UPDATE**

Using `ave()` as @G. Grothendieck suggested works for the blocks, but I'm not sure how it's normalizing beyond that.

```
mat.n <- mat / ave(mat, rownames(mat)[row(mat)], colnames(mat)[col(mat)], FUN = max)
```

Within block the normalization works, e.g.

```
mat[rownames(mat)=="A",colnames(mat)=="A"]
   A  A  A
A 13 18 15
A 38 33 41
A 12 18 47
mat.n[rownames(mat.n)=="A",colnames(mat.n)=="A"]
         A         A         A
A 0.2765957 0.3829787 0.3191489
A 0.8085106 0.7021277 0.8723404
A 0.2553191 0.3829787 1.0000000
```

But beyond that, it looks weird.

```
> round(mat.n,1)
 A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
A 0.3 0.2 0.1 0.4 0.2 1.0 0.3 0.9 1.0
B 0.9 0.8 0.9 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.4 0.9 0.0
C 0.0 0.4 0.4 0.0 0.8 0.5 0.4 0.9 0.0
A 0.8 0.9 0.5 0.7 0.9 0.6 0.9 0.4 0.4
B 0.1 0.8 0.7 1.0 0.3 0.5 0.1 1.0 0.8
C 0.4 0.0 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.6 1.0 0.4 1.0
A 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0 1.0 0.3
B 0.6 0.2 0.5 0.9 0.3 0.2 0.9 0.3 1.0
C 0.5 0.9 0.7 1.0 0.4 0.5 1.0 1.0 0.9
```

In this case, I would expect 3 1s across the whole matrix- 1 for each block. But there're 10 1s, e.g. `mat.n[3,2]`, `mat.n[1,9]`. I'm not sure how this function normalized between blocks.

**UPDATE 2**

```
#Original matrix.
#Suggested solution produces `NaN` 

mat <- as.matrix(read.csv(text=",1.21,1.1,2.2,1.1,1.1,1.21,2.2,2.2,1.21,1.22,1.22,1.1,1.1,2.2,2.1,2.2,2.1,2.2,2.2,2.2,1.21,2.1,2.1,1.21,1.21,1.21,1.21,1.21,2.2,1.21,2.2,1.1,1.22,1.22,1.22,1.22,1.21,1.22,2.1,2.1,2.1,1.22
1.21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,292,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,22,0,0,94,19,79,0,9,0,126,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.1,0,0,0,155,166,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,76,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.1,0,201,0,0,79,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.1,0,33,0,91,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,404,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,37,26,18,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,162,79,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,207,0,0,0,0,1644,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,16,17,402,0,0,0,606,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.22,13,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0
         1.22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,71,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,374,6,121,6,21,0,0,0,0
         1.1,0,0,0,44,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,103,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.1,0,0,0,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,18,0,0,0,0,353,116,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,29,0,5,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,37,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,36,46,62,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,73,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
         2.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,61,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0
         2.2,17,0,23,0,0,0,444,65,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,78,0,0,42,30,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,75,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,87,0,74,0,85,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,19,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,13,0,0,0,12,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,118,0,29,92,0,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,16,0,48,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,14,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,20,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,204,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,133,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,44,0,0
         2.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,67,0,0,0,0,0,0,143,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,12,15,0
         1.21,79,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,34,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,38,26,6,9,0,112,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,11,0,0,0,0,17,0,0,49,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,28,0,0,0,32,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,40,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,122,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,24,11,0,887,20,0,389,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,14,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,0,50,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,34,0,0,0,0,26,0,0,56,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,54,9,297,13,0,0,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,39,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,0,17,12,20,25,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,393,0,7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.21,177,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,775,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,113,0,227,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         2.2,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,17,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,42,30,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,165,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.1,0,6,0,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
         1.22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,37,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,14,7,0,0,18,0,0,0,0
         1.22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,44,785,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,21,0,44,177,13,24,0,0,0,0
         1.22,0,0,0,0,0,0,30,0,0,182,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,7,12,0,1231,135,17,0,0,0,0
         1.22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,73,1308,0,669,16,0,0,0,8
         1.21,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,33,197,626,0,44,0,0,0,0
         1.22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,37,12,80,0,0,0,0,16
         2.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,24,54,0
         2.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,0,0,0,27,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,75,0,0,0
         2.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,58,0,1,0,0,0,0,28,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,61,2,0,0
         1.22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,31,9,0,0,0,0"))

ids <- read.csv(text=",x
1,1.21
                2,1.1
                3,2.2
                4,1.1
                5,1.1
                6,1.21
                7,2.2
                8,2.2
                9,1.21
                10,1.22
                11,1.22
                12,1.1
                13,1.1
                14,2.2
                15,2.1
                16,2.2
                17,2.1
                18,2.2
                19,2.2
                20,2.2
                21,1.21
                22,2.1
                23,2.1
                24,1.21
                25,1.21
                26,1.21
                27,1.21
                28,1.21
                29,2.2
                30,1.21
                31,2.2
                32,1.1
                33,1.22
                34,1.22
                35,1.22
                36,1.22
                37,1.21
                38,1.22
                39,2.1
                40,2.1
                41,2.1
                42,1.22")
mat <- mat[,-1]
rownames(mat) <- ids$x
colnames(mat) <- ids$x
ans <- mat / ave(mat, rownames(mat)[row(mat)], colnames(mat)[col(mat)], FUN = max)
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: There are 9 blocks, not 3 -- AA AB AC BA BB BC CA CB CC. See the comment below my answer and the example added at the end of my answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Many thanks for your explanation!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck In my real matrix, I have 5 groups. I get some `NaN's`, and when turning those into `0s`, `sum(ans == 1)` does not `>=25`. Could this be because some blocks are filled with `0s`?

Comment: Correction: no block contains only `0s`, but some cols/rows have all `0s`. Also, does it matter if the blocks are of different sizes/dims? @G.Grothendieck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ave` to get the maxima:

```
mat / ave(mat, rownames(mat)[row(mat)], colnames(mat)[col(mat)], FUN = max)
```

For example, there are 9 ones, as expected, and there is one 1 in each block also as expected.  (There could be more than 9 if the matrix happened to have multiple maxima in one or more blocks but there shoud not be less than 9.)

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(round(runif(90, 0, 50),),9,9)
rownames(mat) <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],3)
colnames(mat) <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],3)
ans <- mat / ave(mat, rownames(mat)[row(mat)], colnames(mat)[col(mat)], FUN = max)

sum(ans == 1)
## [1] 9

# there are no duplicates (i.e. a block showing up more than once) hence 
# there is exactly one 1 in each block

w <- which(ans == 1, arr = TRUE)
anyDuplicated(cbind(rownames(mat)[w[, 1]], colnames(mat)[w[, 2]]))
## [1] 0
```

ADDED

If some blocks are entirely zero (which is the case in UPDATE 2) then you will get NaNs for those blocks.  If you want 0s instead for the all-zero blocks try this:

```
xmax <- function(x) if (all(x == 0)) 0 else x/max(x)
ave(mat, rownames(mat)[row(mat)], colnames(mat)[col(mat)], FUN = xmax)
```

Comment: So, how/why do this produce 1s outside the blocks? In this case, I would expect 3 1s (one for each block). How are, e.g. blockA-blockB values normalized? 
There are in total 10 1s, e.g. these: 
``mat.n[3,2] #A-B``
``mat.n[7,2] #B-A``

Comment: There are 3x3 = 9 blocks and so if the maximum is unique in each block there should be 9 ones which there are in the example shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the weird thing is that I get `NaNs` outputted. My original matrix does not have any `NAs`. I'm trying to recreate those from the dummy example, i.e. throwing in `0s` and different block sizes, but without success.

Comment: Please see **UPDATE 2** with my original matrix where solution produces `NaNs`.

Comment: In Update 2 some of the blocks are entirely zero.  See ADDED where we output 0s for those blocks instead of NaNs.

Comment: Many thanks! Would it possible to normalize between blocks, i.e., `AB, AC, BA, BC, CA, CB` with the maxima of the block corresponding to the columns, i.e., in the case of `AB` normalize it by `max()` in `BB`, and `AC` by `max()` in `CC` etc.?

Comment: Yes, but that is sufficiently different that it does not really fall within the framework of this answer.

Comment: Please have look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147299/normalize-between-blocks-by-the-maxima-of-the-block-corresponding-to-the-columns Feel free to edit the title appropriately. Thanks!