# Normalize between-blocks by the maxima of the block corresponding to the columns

Tags: r, matrix, normalization, submatrix

This question is a follow-up on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44005847/normalize-blocks-sub-matrices-within-a-matrix)
Instead of normalizing blocks by the local maxima, I would like to normalize between-blocks by the maxima of the block corresponding to the columns.

```
#dummy data
mat <- matrix(round(runif(90, 0, 50),),9,9)
rownames(mat) <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],3)
colnames(mat) <- rep(LETTERS[1:3],3)

#Normalizes within and between blocks by the maxima of the focal block
ans <- mat / ave(mat, rownames(mat)[row(mat)], colnames(mat)[col(mat)], FUN = max)

#Number of blocks
sum(ans == 1)
#[1] 9
```

I would like to normalize between-blocks, i.e.,`AB`, `AC`, `BA`, `BC`, `CA`, `CB` by the maxima of the block corresponding to the columns. E.g., in the case of `AB` normalize it by the `max()` in `BB`, and `AC` by the `max()` in `CC` etc.

```
> mat[rownames(mat)=="A",colnames(mat)=="B"]
  B  B  B
A 26 26 14
A 12 11 18
A 44 44 29

> mat[rownames(mat)=="B",colnames(mat)=="B"]
  B  B  B
B  9 23 20
B 28 45 28
B 14 12 45
```

In this case, normalizing the between-block `AB` not by the maxima of this block (i.e. 44), but by the maxima of block `BB` (i.e. 45).

Any pointers are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `cn` be the vector formed by first replacing each element of `mat` with its column name and then unravelling the resulting matrix column by column.  Similarly do the same thing with the rows giving `rn`.

`(cn == rn) * mat` is the same as `mat` except all non-diagonal blocks are zeroed out.

`v` is a vector whose names are the unique column names and whose values are the maxima of the corresponding diagonal blocks.  The construction of `v` depnds on the fact that the maxima are 0 or more.

`replace(mat, TRUE, v[cn])` is the matrix formed by replacing each element of `mat` with the maximum of the diagonal block in its column and finally we divide `mat` by that.

Note that if any diagonal block is all zeros then the column will be all NaNs; however, there should not be any problem if any off-diagonal blocks are all zeros.

```
cn <- colnames(mat)[col(mat)]
rn <- rownames(mat)[row(mat)]
v <- tapply((cn == rn) * mat,  cn, max)
mat / replace(mat, TRUE, v[cn])
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot!